Is it safe to read/write the raw bytes of a pointer-free struct to disk?
I am playing around with serialization in C. Consider structs that do not contain pointers. Is the in-memory representation of such structs a valid format to be written to and read from disk? More specifically, can I write the bytes of a struct to disk, and then read them back safely?
I have a simple pointer-free struct:
struct point {
    float x; float y;
    char name[16];
};

Writing the struct:
// Get the raw bytes of a struct
struct point p = {4.2, 2.718, "p1"};
uint8_t *raw_p = (uint8_t *)&p;

// Write them to a file
FILE *f = fopen("tmpfile", "wb");
fwrite(raw_p, sizeof(struct point), 1, f);
fclose(f);

Reading the struct back:
// Read the file into a buffer
FILE *f = fopen("tmpfile", "rb");
uint8_t buf[128] = {0};
fread(buf, sizeof(struct point), 1, f);

// Try to convert the bytes to a struct
struct point p = *(struct point *)buf;
printf("point {x: %f, y: %f, name: %s }\n", p.x, p.y, p.name);
fclose(f);

Is this code safe? Is it correct? I am interested in the issues with this approach. Specifically, where does this code fail in terms of portability? Additionally, is this the most performant way to serialize a simple struct?

If you want it to be portable, you should consider endiannes. For example, write all the data to disk in big-endian. That means you first have to convert all the data to big-endian, if your system is little-endian. You also have to convert the data read from disk to little-endian, if the system is little-endian.


Is this code safe?

There are portability concerns (see below), there is a lack of error checking, and there's a potential alignment violation (*(struct point *)buf).

where does this code fail in terms of portability?


Different compilers could use different padding (even on the same machine).
The size and format of floating-point types could vary.
The size and format of signed integral types could vary.
The size of unsigned integral types could vary.
The endianness of values could vary.

Possibly others.

Wouldn't struct point p = *(struct point *)buf; also be a strict-aliasing violation?

@Andrew Henle, Is a typedef for a character type considered a character type? Cause it's not a strict aliasing violation if it's a character type, and uint8_t can't be anything but a typedef for a character type.

Even if uint8_t is a character type, the "exception" part of C11 6.5p7 allows accessing by a character type.  In this case, it's a character type being accessed as a struct.  But then there's also the concept of "effective type", which is the only thing that leads me to believe that struct point p = *(struct point *)buf; might not be a strict aliasing violation.

Problems include:

Without checking the return values of fopen(), fwrite(), fread(), code is not safe.

(struct point *)buf is a problem as alignment is not assured.



Better code
struct point p = {4.2f, 2.718f, "p1"};  // Use float constants
uint8_t *raw_p = (uint8_t *)&p;

FILE *f = fopen("tmpfile", "wb");
if (f) { // Check pointer
  fwrite(raw_p, sizeof p, 1, f); // Size to the obejct
  fclose(f);
}

FILE *f = fopen("tmpfile", "rb");
if (f) { // check pointer
  union {
    uint8_t buf[128];
    struct point;
  } u; // Use an aligned object
  if (fread(u.buf, sizeof u.point, 1, f) == 1) {  // Check results
    struct point p = u.buf;
    printf("point {x: %g, y: %g, name: %s }\n", p.x, p.y, p.name); // Use %g
  }
  fclose(f);
}


There is no need for the buf variable on either input or output.  As long as you're reading on the same machine that you write the file on (or on a machine of the same type) so neither alignment nor endianness is an issue, the code can be written using this code (error checking omitted, but needed in production code):
Writing
struct point p = {4.2, 2.718, "p1"};
FILE *f = fopen("tmpfile", "wb");
fwrite(&p, sizeof(p), 1, f);
fclose(f);

Reading
// Read the file into a buffer
FILE *f = fopen("tmpfile", "rb");
struct point p;
fread(&p, sizeof(p), 1, f);
fclose(f);

Using an intermediary uint8_t buffer provides no benefit and considerable harm — it makes it necessary to worry about alignment, in particular.
